# PHP Generate and autoselect from <select> field

Tags: php

What's wrong with my method? For some reason it won't select the value I typed in `$selected`. What am I overlooking?

```
/**
 * Create the <option> tags for <select> fields
 * @param  array  $arr        Array of options to select, can be assoc or index
 * @param  string  $selected   The selected value if there is any
 * @param  boolean $capitalize Label is capitalized by default. If FALSE label is as written in array
 * @return string              <option> tags ready for echo
 */
public function create_options($arr, $selected = '0', $capitalize = TRUE){
    $str = '';
    foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
        $label = $capitalize ? ucwords($val) : $val;
        $selected = strtolower(trim($selected));
        $key = strtolower(trim($key));
        $val = strtolower(trim($val));
        $selected = '';

        if(is_int($key)) {
            // Numerical
            if($selected == $val) $selected = ' selected';
            $str .= "<option value='{$val}'{$selected}>{$label}</option>";
        } else {
            // Assoc
            if($selected == $key) $selected = ' selected';
            $str .= "<option value='{$key}'{$selected}>{$label}</option>";
        }
    }

    return $str;
}
```

Comment: can you include in your post the output of this function?

Comment: The output is that nothing in the `<select>` field gets selected. It skips the `$selected = ' selected';` entirely even if there's a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `$selected` to empty before using it.

```
 $selected = ''; // Remove this line
```

The value of `$selected` before these conditions is nothing

```
if($selected == $val) $selected = ' selected';
if($selected == $key) $selected = ' selected';
```

None of them will satisfied and `$selected` never sets to `' selected'`.

Comment: No, the two `if` won't work because `$selected` is nothing before conditions, see it again.

Comment: Yes you are right :) I see it +1 In that way the argument is ignored and he compares an empty string.

Comment: I see where I made a mistake. My variables were all named `$selected` which resulting in overwriting the actual value to compare against. Thanks for the answer!